# Can run daily logrotate without cron?

Tags: linux, logging, cron, logrotate, aws-systems-manager

On my docker, i use amazonlinux:2 at this default enviroment **not install cron**.

I want to use logrotate for rotating log of application every daily. **Can Logrotate work automatic without cron?**

This file /etc/logrotate.d/app_log

```
/home/app/logs/*.log {
    daily
    compress
    maxage 7
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Comment: WHat is the problem to install `cron`? And who will create the schedule of logrotate (it there is no cron-like software)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I just want to know if logrotate can work independently without cron? i'm thinking it runs every day by cron at the directory /etc/cron.daily

Comment: I just remember there is such option in `systemd`, but please check this Q/A https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278564/101265

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank for answer. I thik i got the answer (It typically runs once a day via a cron job, and manages logs based on customized rules/settings from its config file.) https://www.vultr.com/docs/using-logrotate-to-manage-log-files/#:~:text=Logrotate%20is%20a%20Linux%20utility,and%20mailing%20of%20log%20files.